# How to config 'Completer.use_jedi' to 'False' in Juypter Notebook permanently

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jedi

Every time a new *jupyter notebook* instance is opened, it requires `%config Completer.use_jedi = False` command to be run, before autocomplete functionality starts working.

This is tiring every time, to config `use_jedi` to *False* before coding.

kindly suggest if there is a permanent fix to have autocomplete in juypter notebook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I launch my jupyterlab from docker and catch this problem.
I solved like this:

```
COPY ipython_kernel_config.py /root/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py
```

Content ipython_kernel_config.py:

```
c.Completer.use_jedi = False
```

idea: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11530

Answer (score 3):

```
# Generate config
ipython profile create
# Edit config file in vim
vim .ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py
# And change 
c.IPCompleter.use_jedi = False in ipython_config.py
```

For More info - https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11530

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28238056)

Comment: @TristanSeifert: There’s not even a link in the answer.

Comment: In JupyterLab the autocomplete feature seems to work out-of-the-box without the need to activate it