# VS Code using Jupyter: Connecting to kernel: Python 3.6.9: Waiting for Jupyter Session to be idle

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am having trouble running my import statement in VS code Jupyter. I split them into individual cells. I find when I run

```
import numpy as np
```

the cell hangs and I get a message

> Connecting to kernel: Python 3.6.9: Waiting for Jupyter Session to be idle

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution was to select the correct version of Python. I had 2 choices for Python 3.6.9. I chose the one called "base(Python 3.6.9)" which had a different location to "Python 3.6.9" and the base version worked. Something odd if going on here, maybe I should remove the other version?

Answer (score 3):

To solve it, I uninstalled the extension Jupyter notebook (which requires a reload), and then installed it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the extended version. I hope this [article](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/9014) is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so this one surprised me..

I was using Jupyter-like code cells "`#%%`" (see [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py)) to run jupyter notebook in VSCode. And I ran into the same issue as OP.

The error disappeared when I renamed my file, from "inspect.py" to "tmp.py".

Answer (score 0):

For me, upgrading `ipython` to version 7.34.0 (from 7.32.0) fixed it. I'm using `jedi` version 0.18.1. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65862512/18758987)

Update: this broke again for me when I upgraded my virtual environment to Python 3.8. I just upgraded my `ipykernel` package and now the notebook runs.