# Jupyter Notebook Tab Completion Not Working without `%config Completer.use_jedi = False`

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Auto completion in Jupyter Notebook only works if I add `%config Completer.use_jedi = False` at the top of my file.

This seems like a very advanced thing for anyone new to Jupyter Notebooks to have to work out.

Why is it required, and is there a way to fix it that doesn't involve messing around with config files as described here:
[How to config 'Completer.use_jedi' to 'False' in Juypter Notebook permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321798/how-to-config-completer-use-jedi-to-false-in-juypter-notebook-permanently)

I'm on windows 10, running `jupyter notebook` from powershell.

`jupyter --version` gives me:

```
jupyter core     : 4.7.0
jupyter-notebook : 6.2.0
qtconsole        : 5.0.1
ipython          : 7.19.0
ipykernel        : 5.4.3
jupyter client   : 6.1.11
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.1.2
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TAB completion does not work in Jupyter Notebook but fine in iPython terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665039/tab-completion-does-not-work-in-jupyter-notebook-but-fine-in-ipython-terminal)

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65702110/6646912

Comment: @krassowski the second answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65702110/3042018 solved it, but it wasn't obvious it was answering the same question, as you would need to check the terminal to see an error had occurred on pressing tab. Maybe obvious in hindsight...

Comment: It is always good to check the terminal when you have any problems with Jupyter as this is where the server-side errors will show up ;)

Comment: Ok, actually this is a better duplicate target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843310/auto-completion-in-jupyter-notebook/65862512#65862512